Sentry ignore node_modules errors
I'm not sure if this is correct question, but I'm struggling with ignoring node_modules in sentry(if possible), the closest I get is ignoreErrors.
I have some errors like that comes from mui x grid, but I don't like Sentry to capture errors for this kind of errors:
SyntaxError
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': ':scope > div > div > div > [data-field="Wall Thickness
(Top / Side / Bottom)"][role="cell"], :scope > div > div > div > [data-field="Wall Thickness
(Top / Side / Bottom)"][role="gridcell"]' is not a...

I'm not too familiar with setting best practices in sentry, I like to hear more, if this is not suitable question, I will close it, as I don't find many topics mentioning excluding node_modules.
            initSentry({
        dsn: 'xxx',
        environment: window.location.hostname,
        integrations: [
            reactRouterV6BrowserTracingIntegration({
                useEffect,
                useLocation,
                useNavigationType,
                createRoutesFromChildren,
                matchRoutes
            }),
            replayIntegration()
        ],
        tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
        replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
        replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
        profilesSampleRate: 1.0,
        ignoreTransactions: [],
        ignoreErrors: sentryIgnoreErrors
    });

